# Asp.Net MVC, Entity Framework, Web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-web-api

I need to add dynamic controls in MVC that I have done through view but I am facing problem in inserting records. My query is there are pre-defined questions based on that answertext boxes will be generating. So each question should display corresponding to its answer.

If there are 20 questions then at run time it will generate 20 answer text boxes which means multiple records are going at once. As far as I know I will do it through DataTable please correct me if I am wrong. But how would I send data through view I am able to perform get request but unable to send multiple records and repository file as well.

Following is my schema
tblAnswer 
AnswerID identity column primary key,
AnswerText varchar(500)
QuestionId foreign key

tblQuestion 
QuestionId primary key identity column
QuestionText

for instance:-

```
@foreach(var ques in Models.questions)//questions is a list of questions
{
       //enter code here
       @ques.QuestionText ///will display question text
       @Html.TextboxFor(model=>model.AnswerText)
       <br/>
}
```

If i take list above then it will force me to take model[i], AnswerText then I need to pass list though I am passing list still not able to perform.

Model

```
public int AnswerId,
public string selectedAnswer,
public int AnswerText, 
public int QuestionId,
public list<Question> questions
```

Selected answer is in radio button there would be 10 radio button on the screen which is also associated with other table. And questiontext does not exist in Answer table

Comment: I would like to make my question more specific, here is my model

Comment: Here is my model: public int AnswerId, public string selectedAnswer, public int AnswerText, public int QuestionId, public list<Question> questions. Selected answer is in radio button there would be 10 radio button on the screen which is also associated with other table. And questiontext does not exist in Answer table.

Answer (score 0):

I would handle this by creating a custom ViewModel that contained a string for the question and a string for the answer entered, then return a collection of these to bind to your view.